# int* pointer not compiling while ushort* and byte* are fine

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged, managed

I do have the follwing struct in a C# wrapper for some unmanaged code. I try to hand over some data using pointers, which is fine for the ushort* and byte* part, but does not work for the fixed int.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe public struct IMAGE
{
    public fixed int nSize[2];
    public ushort* pDepthIm;
    public byte* pColorIm;
}
```

To fill this struct with some information, I use:

```
unsafe public void LoadImage(ushort[] depthImage, byte[] rgbImage, int[] size)
{          
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* pSize = size)
        fixed (ushort* pDepth = depthImage)
        fixed (byte* pRGB = rgbImage)
        {
            _im.nSize = pSize;
            _im.pColorIm = pRGB;
            _im.pDepthIm = pDepth;

            ...
        }
     }
 }
```

At `_im.nSize = pSize;` the compiler shows an error, stating:

> You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions.
>   Try using the fixed statement.

I already noticed that the `int` is initialized in a different way (not with the Pointer-`*`, but as `fixed int`), but I can't figure out how to hand over the value. When hovering over the variable, it is shown as `int*`...

**Update:** I came across the [MSDN error reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/933dxtdw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for the mentioned message. I'm now sure it has to do with the `fixed` statement in the `IMAGE` struct, but I still have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: All the code shown is C#. I added the C++ tag because I'm accessing an unmanaged C++ library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a way to access the `fixed int[2]` like this:

```
public unsafe void LoadImage(ushort[] depthImage, byte[] rgbImage, int[] size)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* pSize = _im.nSize)
        fixed (ushort* pDepth = depthImage)
        fixed (byte* pRGB = rgbImage)
        fixed (S_IMAGE* pim = &_im)
        {
            pSize[0] = size[0];
            pSize[1] = size[1];

            _im.pColorIm = pRGB;
            _im.pDepthIm = pDepth;
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure if this is a good way or if this is how it is meant to be, but at least it works as expected...

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a pointer to an array. You have to use `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(_im.nSize, size, sizeof(_im.nSize));
```

As a matter of fact you can't assign anything to an array. You can modify array's value, but not reassign it.

I would also check for the array length, pass it as a parameter or check it's `.length` if the languge allows it.

Comment: You don't even need to fix `size`. Just copy the two elements with two assignments, or a tiny for loop.

Comment: @usr If the size is wrong, it's a business logic error. Checking whether the input is exactly as we intend it to be before doing something with it is a good practice and it can sometimes save a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like `memcpy` is a c++ function. I'm using C# (sorry if that was unclear in my question).

Comment: I was unclear what I meant. I agree with validating but I did not see the need for memcpy. +1

Comment: @usr memcpy does exactly the same thing what you want to do, and does it in a clear and easily understandable way. It may have worse performance than double assignment, but only slightly. Unless this is 90% of what app does, it'll work just as fast. And is portable, if `nSize` changes to `int[4]` it'll still work well, while 2 assignments won't. I don't understand why you think this is a wrong solution

Comment: Seems to me a more uncommon solution in the .NET world. Even when I use unsafe constructs I try to use as much managed code as I can. Maybe you're right, though.